# Multiple configuration files per machine using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel framework and I'm trying to work with multiple configuration files per machine. 
Depending on the used URL, I will work with one or another config file. Therefore, I can not use the [Environment Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration) files suggested by Laravel docs.

Right now I'm using JSON config files and everything was working well until I had to deal with the Database.

I'm using [Laravel OracleDB plugin](https://github.com/jfelder/Laravel-OracleDB) which works pretty well when the DB config (placed in its `database.php` file) is set statically.

When I try to set the parameters used for the database dynamically, things don't work anymore.

I'm using the `Config::set` function to change those values like so:

```
//BaseController.php
public function __construct(){
    //reading the JSON config file and getting it in a PHP array
    $config= $this->getConfigFile();

    Config::set('oracledb::database.connections.oracle.database', $config['database']);
    Config::set('oracledb::database.connections.oracle.username', $config['username']);
    Config::set('oracledb::database.connections.oracle.password', $config['password']);
}
```

Like this, the configuration for the database should be set before any Controller tries to do anything with the Database.

To my surprise, even the variables are set in the database configuration (as I can check by using `Config::get`), Laravel throws an error as it tries to read the default config file from the plugin instead of the new configuration just being set.

> PDOException
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:635)

What's going on here? Why the `Config::set` seems to work but the models seem to get the database connection parameters from the default database.php file instead of using the values I just set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Wow...very simple solution once I tracked down the problem. Config::set does exactly what it is supposed to do. See [here](https://gist.github.com/jfelder/534bfe095fea4d4cd2d6).

Where the issue comes in is that you are changing the config within the package not within the core DB config. The reconnect calls looks into the base database.conections config while you are changing the oracledb::database configs. Those configs are only merged once when the package is loaded.

To fix, simply remove "oracledb::" from your Config::set like so:

```
Config::set('database.connections.oracle.database', $db['database']);
```

Once I did this, I could get it to work every time. Not sure how the code in the OLD POST worked for me yesterday but it should not have. Correct code below:

```
Config::set(database.connections.oracle.database', $db['database']); 
DB::reconnect('oracle');
```

OLD POST:

I can get it to work by following the Config::set commands with a DB::connection('oracle')->reconnect() command. (See https://gist.github.com/jfelder/1128a7903f6095bd0800)

If you have oracle as your default database then you would just use DB::reconnect().

Since you are using a constructor in your base controller, don't forget to create a constructor in the child class and call parent::__construct() in it since PHP does not do that for you.

Comment: The reconnect doesn't work if I use empty or random values for the database.php initial values. I've answered you with more detail here: https://github.com/jfelder/Laravel-OracleDB/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on the used URL, I will work with one or another config file. Therefore, I can not use the Environment Configuration files suggested by Laravel docs.

Sure you can. While the first example is hostname based, "If you need more flexible environment detection, you may pass a Closure to the detectEnvironment method, allowing you to implement environment detection however you wish." You can write your own custom environment detection code, including basing it on a particular URL.

```
$env = $app->detectEnvironment(function()
{
    if(Request::is('something/*') {
      return 'environment1';
    } else {
      return 'environment2';
    }
});
```

Regarding the `Config::set` calls, we've found that doing these won't affect an already extant connection. For example, one of our functions that dynamically changes the database prefix in our multi-tenant infrastructure does this:

```
Config::set('database.connections.promotion.prefix', $this->id . '_');
DB::connection('promotion')->setTablePrefix($this->id . '_');
```

Comment: I'm using config files which I'm also caching and processing in some way. Is there a way I could use a controller function inside start.php? Otherwise I can't use `Cache::put`, for example.

Comment: Are you sure you need to? It shouldn't typically be necessary to cache the contents of Laravel's environment config files - access from the filesystem is amongst the fastest methods, especially as the OS is going to load that frequently used file into cache.

Comment: See my edit for what's likely happening to your `Config::set` calls.

Comment: About the cache, it's a large json file which I'm reading by using `file_get_contents` and then converting to php by using `json_decode($json, true);`. If that can be cached I believe it would be faster.

Comment: `json_decode` is pretty speedy, and the `file_get_contents` will benefit from the OS-level cache. You might want to benchmark to see if it's worth the effort. I'd suggest just converting the JSON into a Laravel-style config PHP file.

Comment: I can not even call the `storage_path()` function from the `start.php.`

Comment: I don't see any option in the connection class to set the Database params again.

Comment: `DB::reconnect()` might do it.

Comment: I already tried it. Nothing. I tried `DB::reconnect('oracle');` Still having the same issue.

Comment: Also, trying your suggestion I get `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Request' not found in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\laravel\bootstrap\start.php on line 57`